# Difference between 'rafa' and 'ripa'

Tags: words, hebrew, grammar-dikduk, medicine

The root רפא, "heal", is used in various places in *Tanach*, sometimes in *binyan paal* and sometimes in *binyan piel*. I wonder what the difference is between these. Does any *Tanach* commentator, or the like, comment on the difference — in *Tanach* (i.e., ignore *l'shon chazal*) — between these two verbs?

---

I thought (based on a couple of examples) that when God is the [agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_%28grammar%29), the verb is in *paal*, and that when a person is the agent, the verb's in *piel*. But that's not the case; for example:

- *B'reshis* 20:17: וַיִּרְפָּא אֱלֹקִים אֶת אֲבִימֶלֶךְ: God is the agent, and the verb is in *paal*.
- *B'reshis* 50:2: וַיְצַו יוֹסֵף אֶת עֲבָדָיו אֶת הָרֹפְאִים לַחֲנֹט אֶת אָבִיו: People are the agents, and the verb is in *paal*.
- *Sh'mos* 21:19: רַק שִׁבְתּוֹ יִתֵּן וְרַפֹּא יְרַפֵּא: A person is the agent, and the verb is in *piel*.
- Ⅱ *M'lachim* 2:21: רִפִּאתִי לַמַּיִם הָאֵלֶּה: God is the agent, and verb is in *piel*.

Comment: There are a bunch of verbs which sometimes switch kind of randomly between the two binyanim (רדפ דבר come to mind). The best I can suggest is that the Piel forms are meant to be "stronger".

Comment: In your second example, where is the verb? _(ha-)Rof'im_ ( plural of _Rofe'_) is a noun. Both other examples you brought do follow the rule that you say "[is] not the case".

Comment: @TamirEvan, _rof'im_ is a verb form, used as a substantive.

Comment: @msh210 Technically true, but it is used here as a noun for 'physician(s)\doctor(s) in it's own right, so it needn't be bound by rules for proper conjugation of verbs.

Comment: @TamirEvan, even if you're correct that, because it's being used as a noun, _rofe_ needn't have the usual meaning of the _paal_ verb, I've added an example now from _M'lachim_ that shows my conjecture to have been false.